# snake does not eat the food in vertical

Tags: c

I already finished  my snake game and it look pretty good when I execute it into cool retro term:

[image: snake game in retro term]

I need some help to fix some bugs when I try to use other unicode codes for the food, I got a frog unicode character, when I eat in horizontal way is just fine but in vertical if I need to eat from the first part if I made it from the right part of the emjo does not anything.

[image: frog]

Here is my code:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <curses.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#define N 20
#define M 40
int i,j,Field[N][M],x,y,gy,Head,Tail,Game,Frogs,a ,b,var,dir,score,HighScore=0,speed=150;
FILE *f;
void snakeInitialization(){
  f=fopen("highscore.txt","r+");
    rewind(f);
  fscanf(f,"%d",&HighScore);
  fclose(f);
  for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(j=0;j<M;j++){
      Field [i][j]=0;
    }
  }
  x=N/2;
  y=M/2;
  Head=5;
  Tail=1;
  gy=y;
  Game = 0;
  Frogs = 0;
  a = 0;
  b = 0;
  var = 0;
  dir = 'd';
  score = 0;
  speed = 150;
  for(i=0;i<Head;i++)
  {
    gy++;
    Field[x][gy-Head]=i+1;
  }
}
int kbhit(void)    /* comment */
{
    int ch, r;

    // turn off getch() blocking and echo
    nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
    noecho();

    // check for input
    ch = getch();
    if( ch == ERR)      // no input
            r = FALSE;
    else                // input
    {
            r = TRUE;
            ungetch(ch);
    }

    // restore block and echo
    nodelay(stdscr, FALSE);
    return(r);
}
int msleep(long msec)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    int res;

    if (msec < 0)
    {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }

    ts.tv_sec = msec / 1000;
    ts.tv_nsec = (msec % 1000) * 1000000;

    do {
        res = nanosleep(&ts, &ts);
    } while (res && errno == EINTR);

    return res;
}

void print()
{
  wchar_t RDC = 0x255D;//right down corner simbol
  wchar_t LDC = 0x255A;//left down corner unicode simbol
  wchar_t VW = 0x2551;//vertical wall simbol
  wchar_t HW = 0x2550;//Horizontal wall simbol
  wchar_t RUC = 0x2557;//right up corner simbol
  wchar_t LUC = 0x2554;//left up corner simbol
  wchar_t HS = 0x2593;
  wchar_t BS = 0x2591;
  wchar_t Frg = 0x1318F;//frog
  // wprintf(L"unicode code  255A prints  %lc\n", LDC);
  // wprintf(L"unicode code 2551 prints %lc\n",VW);
  // wprintf(L"unicode code 2550 prints %lc\n",HW);
  // wprintf(L"unicode code 255D prints %lc\n",RDC);
  // wprintf(L"unicode code 2557 prints %lc\n",RUC);

  // printf ("asscii of 188 gives: %c\n\n",188);
  // printf("%c", 65);
  for (i=0;i<=M+1;i++)
  {
    if(i==0)
    {
      printw("%lc",LUC);
    }
    else if (i==M+1){
      printw("%lc",RUC);
    }
    else{
      printw("%lc",HW);
    }
  }
  printw( "Current Score: %d | HighScore: %d",score,HighScore);
  printw("\n");
  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
  {
    printw("%lc",VW);
    for (j=0;j<M;j++)
    {
      if(Field[i][j]==0) printw(" ");
      if(Field[i][j]>0&&Field[i][j]!=Head) printw("%lc",BS);
      if(Field[i][j]==Head) printw("%lc",HS);
      if(Field[i][j]==-1) printw("%lc",Frg);
      if(j==M-1) printw("%lc\n",VW);
    }
  }
  for (i=0;i<=M+1;i++)
  {
    if(i==0)
    {
      printw("%lc",LDC);
    }
    else if (i==M+1){

      printw("%lc",RDC);
    }
    else{
      printw("%lc",HW);
    }
  }
}
void ResetScreenPosition(){
  move(0, 0);
}
void Random (){
  srand(time(0));
  a = 1 + rand() % 18;
  b = 1 + rand() % 38;
  if (Frogs == 0 && Field[a][b]==0) {
    Field[a][b] = -1;
    Frogs = 1;
    if(speed>10 && score!=0){
      speed = speed -2;
    }
  }
}
// long int getch_noblock(){
//   if(!kbhit())
//     return getch();
//   else
//     return -1;
// }
long int getch_noblock(){
  if(kbhit())
    return getch();
  else
    return -1;
}
void GameOver(){
  system("clear");
    if(score>HighScore){
    mvprintw(N/2, M/2, " New HighScore %d !!!! \n\n",score);
    refresh();
    getch();
    f=fopen("highscore.txt", "w+");
    rewind(f);
    fprintf(f, "%d", score);
    fclose(f);
}
  system("clear");

   mvprintw(N/2, M/2, "GameOver\n \t \t    score:%d \n\n Press the letter 'p' to play again or the letter 'e' to exit",score);
  refresh();

    while(1){
        var = getch_noblock();
        if(var == 'p'){
            Game = 0;
            system("clear");
            snakeInitialization();
            clear();
            refresh();
            break;
        }else if(var == 'e'){
            Game = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}

void movement(){
  var = getch_noblock();
  var = tolower(var);
  if (((var == 'd' || var == 'a') || (var == 'w' || var == 's')) &&( abs(dir-var)>5)){
    dir=var; 
  }
  if (dir == 'd'){
    y++;
    if(y==M-1){
      y=0;
    }

    if(Field[x][y]!=0 && Field[x][y]!=-1){
      GameOver();
    }
    if(Field[x][y]==-1){
      Frogs=0;
      score += 5;
      Tail -= 2;
    }
    Head++;
    Field[x][y]=Head;
  }
  if (dir == 'a'){
    y--;
    if(y==0){
      y=M-1;
    }

    if(Field[x][y]!=0 && Field[x][y]!=-1){
      GameOver();
    }

       if(Field[x][y]==-1){
      Frogs=0;
      score += 5;
      Tail -= 2;
    }
 
    Head++;
    Field[x][y]=Head;
  }
  if (dir == 'w'){
    x--;
    if(x==-1){
      x=N-1;
    }
    if(Field[x][y]!=0 && Field[x][y]!=-1){
      GameOver();
    }

    
  if(Field[x][y]==-1){
      Frogs=0;
      score += 5;
      Tail -= 2;
   }
 
    Head++;
    Field[x][y]=Head;
  }
  if (dir == 's'){
    x++;
    if(x==N){
      x=0;
    }

    if(Field[x][y]!=0 && Field[x][y]!=-1){
      GameOver();
    }

       if(Field[x][y]==-1){
      Frogs=0;
      score += 5;
      Tail -= 2;
   }
  
    Head++;
    Field[x][y]=Head;
  }
}
void TailRemove(){
  for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    for (j=0; j<M; j++) {
      if (Field[i][j]==Tail) {
        Field[i][j] = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  Tail++;
}
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
  snakeInitialization();  // moving cursor, x = 20, y = 10
  initscr();
  curs_set(0);
  while (Game == 0) {
    print();
    ResetScreenPosition();
    Random();
    movement();
    TailRemove();
    msleep(speed);
    refresh();

  }
  endwin();
  return 0;
}
```

i think this one is the part that i need to modifi to do this but i can come up when idea

```
void Random (){
  srand(time(0));
  a = 1 + rand() % 18;
  b = 1 + rand() % 38;
  if (Frogs == 0 && Field[a][b]==0) {
    Field[a][b] = -1;
    Frogs = 1;
    if(speed>10 && score!=0){
      speed = speed -2;
    }
  }
}
```

I was trying to use emojis instead of simple character for the food.

Comment: thanks dude , i did the changes but it still not working

Comment: i think it has to be with the spaces, in cool retro term happend this [link](https://imgur.com/lJSjrLW) as you can see the snake just doge the food becose an extra space that now is part of the frog character

Comment: This example is rather cumbersome, so you may have trouble finding help. At a glance, some problems: directives like `#include <cctype>` indicates you are probably using a C++ compiler, combining `system("clear");` with (n)curses routines is at best a strange idea (use `clear` or `erase`), and that is *a lot* of global variables to try and follow through your program. Additionally, see [srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7343833/2505965), and consider [`napms`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/napms.html) for brevity.

Comment: yes but i think it has to be with the space that i use to print the fied becose with other characters as you can see in the first gif the wall in the part where the food appears is pushed an space. out of the rest of the wall, so reduce one space in the line where the food appears may be a solution but i do not know how to make that happen

Comment: As a side note, in `movement()` you do the exact same thing for all four directions after modifying `x` and `y`, respectively, so you might want to move that logic below the last `if` there and only have it once.

Comment: i think i am moving forward into the problem i fix the pare whre the programs prints one more space  in the frog takes the space of tho characters by adding 1 at the j variable  afther the character of the frog was printed but it still stuck traying that the snake detects all the emoji